# can i use wild card query in endswith method in java

Tags: java

i need to get all the files ends with `.doc` and  i have some custom extensions like `.doc.25-40`,
`.doc2` etc..i need to get all the extensions with `.doc.*`

```
filename.endsWith(".doc.*");
```

fails why?

Comment: Just a comment to let you know that all Java standard classes are well documented, and that you could have discovered why it doesn't work by just reading the javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that doesn't work. Java doesn't support simple wildcards. You would have to use a Regex method, e.g.:

```
filename.matches(".*\\.doc.*")
```

Explanation:

```
.*   // any text
\\.  // a period
doc  // "doc"
.*   // any text
```

Comment: @Peter hadn't seen that one, changed now

Comment: @Sean, adding a \\b as `.*\\.doc\\b.*` might be an improvement, to avoid matching `my.document.xls`

Comment: @Peter true, but that wouldn't match .doc2 anymore

Comment: Perhaps `.*\\.doc[\\-\\.0-9]*` is required or even `.*\\.[dD][oO][cC][\\-\\.0-9]*` in case it is upper case.

Comment: @Peter it's easier to embed a case insensitive flag, e.g.: `.*\\.(?i)doc.*`, see [special constructs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special)

Answer (score 4):

Because that is the same as

```
filename.contains(".doc");
```

It fails because the String comparison is literal e.g. file.DOC will fail as well.

Answer (score 1):

String.endsWith() looks for a specific char sequence, you cannot use wildcards. What you are looking for is String.matches(String regex) that uses regular expressions.

`filename.matches(".*\\.doc.*")`